# Assigning arrays as keys and values of a map

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I have two arrays of Type String:

```
String [] a;
String [] b;
```

and then a map

```
Map<String, String> mapNumeric = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

I want *a* to be the keys and *b* the value. So it will look like this:

- elementOfA = elementOfB
- otherElementOfA = otherElementOfB

And so on...

`mapNonNumeric.put( a, b);` does not work I tried to pass element by element by doing:

```
for( String key : a) {
   mapNumeric.put( key, new String() );}
for( String value: b) {
   mapNumeric.put(new String(), value );}
```

That is not good either because the new String() will erase the previous value. Also if you do nested for loops it assigns all the values of the array b as values of the first element of array that will create the keys.

Please help if someone knows how to assign one array for the keys and another array for the values of the same map, or if you know other structure that will do the trick. Thanks.
PS I am working in Java

Update
Fix the String[] I am learning how to use maps so it was a mistake. Thanks to your advise is now working

Comment: Where is the declaration for mapNonNumeric?

Comment: You are not really using a `Map<String[], String[]>`, as @Fildor's answer points out.  But even if you were, it would not be a good idea.  You should rarely use putable data as the keys of a `HashMap`.  If `a` and `b` are arrays, and you do `map.put(a, b); a[0] = "xyzzy";` then `a` now is in the wrong hash bucket, and the map from `a` to `b` gets lost.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by using a String array as a key of a Map. A key should provide their own implementation of equals and hashCode methods. How would you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
String [] a = getA();
String [] b = getB();
Map<String, String> mapNumeric = new HashMap<>();
for (int i=0; i < Math.min(a.length, b.length); i++) {
   mapNumeric.put(a[i], b[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You declared the map to use **arrays** of strings to be used.

If you want to `put(x,y)` where x and y are String , then you have to declare it `Map<String,String>`.

For your case, x would be one element of a , y an element of b.

You'll have to iterate over a and b to insert all of them into the Map as you can see in various answers by now.

Comment: a and b are arrays of strings, look at his code.

    String [] a;
    String [] b;

Comment: @PandaBearSoup: I know. These are different a and b ;) Couldn't post an example fast enough to make that clear.

Comment: Furthermore, the string arrays must be iterated both at same loop : `for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)  map.put(a[i], b[i]);`

Comment: @user2501722 I've seen (and probably made) worse ;)

Answer (score 1):

The way you defined it you have one array as a key and the other one as the value for that key. You may want it like this:

```
String[] keys   = getKeys();    // magic
String[] values = getValues();  // magic
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
   map.put(keys[i], values[i];
}
```

(assuming keys and values have the same length)

Comment: he doesnt want a map of the strings, he wants to put multiple arrays in the map.

Comment: @PandaBearSoup not really sure, sounds to me like he has the keys in array a and the values in b and now wants a map instead of two arrays.

Comment: That's what I thought, too.

Comment: From the original post:

> I want a to be the keys and b the value. So it will look like this:
> 
> elementOfA = elementOfB
> otherElementOfA = otherElementOfB

Comment: @Andreas_D oh you may be right, which makes his question a bit silly.

Comment: @PandaBearSoup There no silly questions if you are a beginner. He's still learning, I guess.

Comment: @user2501722 Sorry 'bout that. "He" was ment in the neutral sense of "the OP"

Answer (score 0):

```
String [] a = whatever;
String [] b = whatever;
int minSize = Math.min(a.length, b.length);
Map<String, String> mapNumeric = new HashMap<String, String>(minSize);

for (int i = 0; i < minSize; i++) {
  mapNumeric.put(a[i], b[i]);
}
```